# Initialize / warm-start search

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

How can I warm-start or initialize my cp_model from a previously found solution? I have the solution stored as booleans which I need to assign to my NewBoolVars.

Edit: so far I am using python

Comment: Yes, that answers it perfectly. Thanks.